# Distributing files with an Android application

Tags: android, database

I wanted to build an application that would have its own database. I know that LiteSQL can be used, but apart from that I am allowed to use standard file system using FileInputStream and FileOuputStream.

I know I can create file with FileOutputStream and it will get written to /data/data/com.mydomain/files/ directory. I also know that once the file is written it's going to stay there and it will be available for reading next time the application runs.

My question is: how can I distribute the file with the application? I don't want to be forced to create the file during the first run of the application. I would rather create it before the application gets packaged.

In fact, if I decided to use LiteSQL instead, I would face similar problem. Right?

Thanks in advance,

M.K.

Answer (score 0):

You can place any resources that do not need to be compiled in to the `/res/raw` directory.

You could place your file in there and on the first run of the app read the file using the `getResources().openRawResource()` method and then write the contents into a file on the device.

In the past I have used a database dump file from the `/res/raw` directory to do an initial population of a database (this can be time consuming if you have a lot of data to insert though). It might be possible to put the actual SQLite database file in there, which you could just copy to the device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I may put some data file in /res/raw directory and I will try to read it from there. I am new to Android, but I expected that there would be some standard way for delivering applications with some embedded data file. For example: application uses a list of towns and user can add new towns to the list. The application needs to have the list of towns stored somewhere. It sounds strange to me that the application in such case has to detect the first run and populate the database instead of delivering pre-prepared data file.